# How to set path variable in Windows Server 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, environment-variables

Can someone help me figure out how to set a variable path in Windows Server 2003? I am trying to do the below code which is not working.

Update:  My issue might actually be that the CURRENT PATH needs to be up one level.  How do I set the current path to the current path but up one directory higher?

```
set CURRENT_PATH=%CD%
echo CURRENT_PATH = %CURRENT_PATH%
```

I tried both these ways.

```
set RELEASE_DIR=%CURRENT_PATH%\release
echo RELEASE_DIR = %RELEASE_DIR%

set RELEASE_DIR=%CD%\release
echo RELEASE_DIR = %RELEASE_DIR%

set WIN_RUN_CMD=runBuild.cmd %CD% %CD%\cmtmp
set WIN_RUN_CMD=runBuild.cmd %CURRENT_PATH% %CURRENT_PATH%\cmtmp
```

I have come across individuals saying to use for example, %~d0. I have tried this and it does not appear to be working on Windows Server 2003.

Answer (score 0):

Set the current path to 
%CURRENT_PATH%..

.. = parent directory.
. = current directory.

(ever notice on a DIR listing there are two directories - .. and .?)

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and it didn't work. Gave me errors. However, I did figure it out. I had to use pushd and popd. set CURRENT_PATH=%CD% echo CURRENT_PATH = %CURRENT_PATH% pushd .. set BUILD_PATH=%CD% echo BUILD_PATH = %BUILD_PATH% popd